# discord_components discord.py know which user clicked the button

Tags: button, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot with discord.py, to handle the buttons I'm using discord_compontens.
I have a button and I wanna know which user clicked it, docs didn't help me, I think this library it's not the best choice to handle buttons, for this reason if there is a better library that can do what I want to do I can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an interaction I suppose, like this:

```
interaction = await self.bot.wait_for("button_click")
```

Then it's enough to do:

```
interaction.user
```

To get the user that clicked the button, anyway [here](https://giters.com/injoon5/discord.py-buttons) there is a good list of others features, like guild, etc...